# Retaining the data in the view during activity switch?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, view, android-activity

In my android app the user can enter the text in the EditView and the click on a button which takes him to an other activity where he can select a contact ... and then press a button which
brings him back to the first activity...

now the problem is I need to pass the selected contact to the first activity and display it (which i have done it using a bundle) but i am unable to retain already entered text in the EditView... which i should do (but the text should be retained with out passing it through the the bundle and getting it back)

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in a view component is automagically saved by the OS, even after a soft kill (user changed phone orientation), but not after a hard kill, the user hit the back button while the parent activity was in focus. So, unless you are doing something non-standard, such as calling onSaveInstanceState without calling super.onSaveInstanceState, the data in the view state should persist.

One solution would be to save the text in the view component as a non view instance property  before you launch the child activity, and just read this value back when the focus returns to the parent activity in the method onActivityResult.

JAL

EDIT: The [Android Docs Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) page has been extensively updated. View state will not be saved if the widget does not have an ID.

EDIT: What I am saying is that the view state should be persisted by the OS. You should not need to save the view state manually. On a hard kill, you would need to save the state of your activity IF that is the expected behavior of the activity. So here is some code that saves the activity state. Given an instance variable:

```
String password;
```

Here we save state on a soft kill:

```
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        password= editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        outState.putString("password", password);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // save view state
    }
```

Here we save state on a hard kill

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putString("password",password); 
  editor.commit();
```

Here we restore state in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState):

```
if( savedInstanceState!= null){ // get saved state from soft kill after first pass
    try {
        password= savedInstanceState.getString("password");
        Log.d(TAG,"RestoredState!");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"FailedToRestoreState",e);
    }
}
else { // get saved state from preferences on first pass
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); // singleton
    if (prefs != null){
        this.password= prefs.getString("password","");    
        Log.d(TAG,"gettingPrefs");
    }
}
Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
```

Also given the fact that IF onSaveInstanceState is called it will be called before onStop, it is possible to use the flags isSavedInstanceState and isSavedPreferences to write to prefs ONLY on a hard kill if you reset the flags in onResume as:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG,"onResume");
    isSavedInstanceState= false;
    isSavedPrefs= false;
}
```

Setting the flags in onCreate will not result in the desired outcome.

Comment: how to save the text in the view component as a non view instant property ...can u give me some examples pls :)

Comment: @kAnNaN I edited my answer to show some code. Hope that helps.